# A GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated when call glBufferSubData

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I want to make the GLTools launching on Android devices.(GLTools is a library of OpenGL SuperBible). The Book only talks about iOS but no Android.
There are a problem.

```
void GLBatch::CopyVertexData3f(M3DVector3f *vVerts) 
{
// First time, create the buffer object, allocate the space
if(uiVertexArray == 0) {
    glGenBuffers(1, &uiVertexArray);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiVertexArray);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3 * nNumVerts, vVerts, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    }
else    { // Just bind to existing object
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiVertexArray);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "CopyVertexData3f", "uiVertexArray = %d", 
        glIsBuffer(uiVertexArray));
    // Copy the data in
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3 * nNumVerts, vVerts);
    //glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3 * nNumVerts, vVerts, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    pVerts = NULL;
    }
}
```

If the variable uiVertexArray is not zero. The Code will enter in else block and throw A GL_INVALID_OPERATION like this :

```
<qgl2DrvAPI_glBufferSubData:769>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if the reserved buffer object name 0 is bound to target.
But uiVertexArray is not zero. Why code throws GL_INVALID_OPERATION when call glBufferSubData?

Once I change glBufferSubData to glBufferData, it works.

Comment: It is also called if the buffer is mapped. Could you try to explicitly unmap it? Also I hope you are calling this on the correct thread (the same thread you make the context).

Comment: The error might also occur if you try to write beyond the end of the buffer. Are you sure that `nNumVerts` is not bigger than at the time the buffer was intially created?